# How to find out those words that repeate one character more than twice in a word(such as "aa,aaxx")

Tags: bash, grep

I want to find all vocabulary from a text file(It convert from a true ebook,so maybe bigger,and the solution need to be effecient), and I have output the vocabulary in a text file named voclist.But still have some illegal words I want to remove it, such as (aa,aazzz).

I have tried "egrep [a-z]+ voclist".
Surely, it won't work.

```
This is the block contain illegal words:
      2 accepting
      2 absence
      1 zz
      1 yyybb
      1 yarn

I want output like this:
      2 accepting
      2 absence
      1 yarn
```

I think about this question much times. Remove "yyybb" and remain "accepting" at the same time maybe a little diffcult, and "yyybb" is rarely occured in a true ebook,so we can just remove "zz".Anybody have any idea?

Comment: Your question is a bit fuzzy on the edges. How do you define _illegal words_?

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I said illegal, just want to mean that the word is a set of characters(don't mean anything) and it won't occur in normal conversation or book. Maybe it occured in perfessional book(like "awk & sed"). Sorry for that I didn't describe it clearly in question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The format you have is a bit unhandy. It looks like it comes from a combination of `sort` and `uniq -c`. For simplification, I'll assume the following input format:

```
accepting
absence
zz
yyybb
yarn
```

In a bit a lengthy way, you could write:

```
 $ grep -v -e '^.$'                          \ # single char
           -e '^\(.\)\1$'                    \ # single repeated char (e.g. zzzz)
           -e '\(.\)\1\+'                    \ # repeated char (3 or more times)
           -e '^[aeiou]\+$'                  \ # only vowels
           -e '^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]\+$'  \ # only consonants
           file
```

We make use of `grep` as it supports backreferencing in the matching part. Something that awk does not allow.

It is now possible to use this on the original format as:

```
awk '{print $2}' file \
    | grep -v -e '^.$' -e '^\(.\)\1$' -e '\(.\)\1\+'            \
              -e '^[aeiou]\+$' -e '^[bcdfghjklmnpqrstvwxyz]\+$' \
    | grep -wFf - file
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! And it's helpful. You are right, the file is a combination of "sort" and "uniq -c", and the format is a bit unhandy. Your answer reminded me that use "grep -v -e '^.$'..." before "sort" and "uniq -c". Above all, thanks!

Comment: @Dsp be aware there is a little typo in the repeated char case (the `$` should be removed)

Comment: Of course, I know that, though I'm freshman to English and linux. :(

Comment: @Dsp no, I just wanted to say that I made an error in the above case. I was not saying that you made a mistake. The mistake is now corrected.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose `inputfile` contains:

```
  2 accepting
  2 absence
  1 zz
  1 yyybb
  1 yarn
```

To get a list of words with two or more repeated characters:

```
$ egrep "(\w)\w*\1" inputfile
2 accepting
2 absence
1 zz
1 yyybb
```

and to filter illegal words you could use a dictionary, e.g.

```
$ cat dictionary
accepting
absence
```

and compare against it:

```
$ egrep "(\w)\w*\1" inputfile | grep -f dictionary
2 accepting
2 absence
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer.But I afraid that use dictionary isn't the best idea.In fact,the inputfile will be a vocabulary list from a true book, more than thousands lines.Use a dictionary will be slowly.

Comment: `\w` is a Perl extension which isn't commonly supported by `egrep`. Try `grep -P` instead if you have that; or convert to a regex like `([[:alnum:]])[[:alnum:]]*\1`